# Share Customer and its PaymentMethods with Connected Accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm building a platform where content creators can setup a subscription service of which I'll take a fee (think Twitch.tv, Substack, OnlyFans, etc.)

Content creators will setup a Stripe Connected Account on the platform. I'll operate the Platform Account.

Customers that subscribe to a content creator might want to subscribe to others so it makes sense to keep both `Customers` and their `PaymentMethods` on the Platform Account. Customers must be able to manage all their subscriptions and have their credit card details pre-filled, if already available.

I can't, for the life of me, understand how to share these `Customers` and their `PaymentMethods` with the content creator's Connected Accounts.

I followed the [clone customers across accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-saved-payment-methods) guide unsuccessfully. It errors out while creating the `Token`, saying that the `Customer` must have an active payment source. I read somewhere that this guide doesn't work with `PaymentMethods` but I don't really know if that's true.

Then I found [this other guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods). It seems, though, that I would have to create a `Customer`, per User, per Connected Account which will make me duplicate information and make subscription management harder.

Could anyone, who has experience building a similar service, give me some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having exactly same problem, did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope, and I ended up abandoning the project. I even contacted Stripe support and left a comment on their subreddit but it was wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cloning PaymentMethods to your connected accounts (for which [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods) is the correct one) you could create [subscriptions using destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#transfer). The idea being that the customers and payment methods stay on your platform account. When an invoice is paid its funds (minus an application fee set by you) are automatically transferred to the connected account.

Comment: That was my original idea but the Connected Account and Platform Account must be in the same region for this to work. Or I must use `on_behalf_of` which is still in beta, for subscriptions, as you can read on the page you linked.